# Spring Data Rest search endpoint

Tags: spring-data-rest

We are trying to adopt standardization in the rest endpoints and would like to know why Spring Data Rest exposes FindBy operations using the "search" endpoint.  For example http://localhost:8080/ws_springtcri_next/events/search/findByEventCityIn.  Is this a standard priniciple?

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Integer>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event>, 
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Event> {
        Page<Event> findByEventCityIn(
            @Param("eventCity") Collection<String> cities, Pageable pageable);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All query repository method resources are exposed under the search resource, as they doing search for entities in db matching some criteria. You can not change this /search url. If you really need a link without search, you should override response handler for the entity via writing your own controller with annotation @RepositoryRestController